# Как вставить переменную-счетчик в аргумент фу-ии CreateDirectory?

Tags: c++, c

```
#include <windows.h>
int main()
{
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++);
        CreateDirectory("D:\\Doc\\dir сюда", NULL);
}
```

Comment: `CreateDirectory` вообще к делу не относится. Обычная работа со строками.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Например:

```
char buf[MAX_PATH];
sprintf(buf,"D:\\Doc\\dir\\_%02d",i);
CreateDirectory(buf,...
```

Можно чуть плюсатее:

```
CreateDirectory(("D:\\Doc\\dir\\"+to_string(i)).c_str(),...
```

Можно и сложно :)

```
ostringstream os;
os << "D:\\Doc\\dir\\" << i;
CreateDirectory(os.str().c_str(),...
```

Comment: не совсем понятно что значит %02d, что значит  02 перед d ?

Comment: `MAX_PATH` не очень правильно: это не спасёт от срыва буфера, если путь получится слишком длинным. А почему не просто `std::string`?

Comment: @VladD Ну можно взять `snprintf`. Ваш вариант сейчас допишу как промежуточный, спасибо.

Comment: @Антонв Ну, чтоб не просто `dir\1`, `dir\2` и так далее, а с нуликом: `dir\01`, `dir\02`. так оно красивее :)

Comment: @Abyx Спасибо, вношу соответствующее исправление.